# Set the height of an <aside> element equal to height of an <article> element but not less than the height of browser

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<section>
  <aside> </aside>
  <article> </article>
</section>
```

I need to have height of `aside` = height of `article`, but not less then browser height.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/demas/4hzLbt78/

Now the the height of `aside` = heigth of browser, but when the content of `article` is big I have the white space on the left side of the page (on the bottom part of them).

**Update:**  I use jeet grid (http://jeet.gs/) and can not change `float: left` for `aside` and `article`.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hgfe0hdg/

Comment: @JoshCrozier absolute positioning maybe is not that OP wants. It's a good solution. However, mix `float:left` and `position:Absolute` makes no sense for me-.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude You can't really mix `float: left` and `position: absolute`. If it's absolutely positioned, then floating it won't have any effect on the element. `float: left` can just be removed, but based on the OP's update, he can't change that, so I just left it in there to show that it essentially overrides that behavior.

Comment: @JoshCrozier, thanks. It is what I was needed.  Can you please create the answer?

Comment: @JoshCrozier I know that, it's because the mixin have no sense. I said to you that's a good answer anyway. I don't critic this, only try to avoid mixing incompatible properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the width of the `aside` element is known in advance, one option would be to absolutely position the element *relative* to the parent `section` element, and then displace the element by adding an `margin-left` on the `article`.

The `aside` element can now have the same height as the parent element (using `top: 0; bottom: 0`), and since the parent element's height is determined by the height of the `article` element, the `aside`/`article` elements will have the same height.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/LeezLm5c/)

```css
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
  width: 18%;
  color: #feffff;
  background-color: #2a5c83;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

article {
  float: left;
  width: 76%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside></aside>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.
  </article>
</section>
```

#### Alternatives:

Using a flexbox layout:

```css
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  width: 18%;
  color: #feffff;
  background-color: #2a5c83;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

article {
  width: 76%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside></aside>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.
  </article>
</section>
```

Using `display: table`/`display: table-cell`:

```css
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: table;
}

aside {
  width: 18%;
  color: #feffff;
  background-color: #2a5c83;
  display: table-cell;
}

article {
  width: 76%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside></aside>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempor at massa et rutrum. Duis ac viverra lorem. Integer volutpat, libero a molestie suscipit, nisi lacus elementum nisi, non cursus arcu sapien id mauris. Nullam dignissim diam eu tellus varius finibus. Nam consectetur, libero vel efficitur malesuada, nunc enim laoreet tellus, id ornare ipsum lacus vel ligula. Pellentesque semper scelerisque enim, id euismod enim accumsan sit amet. Pellentesque vel vulputate lorem, eu ornare turpis. Duis rhoncus purus eu mi rutrum, eu pellentesque enim dignissim. Aenean felis nisl, ultrices eget placerat eget, viverra a mi.
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. Two questions :) First: `Since you have a fixed width on the aside element` - what do you mean ? I have the width in percents.  And second:  can you please provide a solution in the ideal case when we can remove `float` tag ?

Comment: @demas I just meant *'fixed'* as in "it will always have the same width, `18%`, and it won't change", that way we know how much space to displace. Here are the ideal solutions - [using flexboxes](https://jsfiddle.net/hnm0rjd9/), and [using `display: table`](https://jsfiddle.net/6hr7z59c/).

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox, obviously

```
section {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4hzLbt78/1/)

Comment: That's not work. Try with the complete text in the OP's fiddle

Comment: But if the text in the article is bigger I have the same problem.

Comment: I think that there are two solutions: `display: table-cell` or javascript calculations